# How to convert a decimal value to hexadecimal and the output should be 16 digits

Tags: python-2.7

How to convert a decimal number to a hexadecimal number of 16 digits?
The decimal number is 1198540479 and am trying to convert it to hexadecimal .
For this , I did >>> hex(1198540479) and getting output as '0x477046bf' where as I am expecting output '0x00000000477046bf'.

Answer (score 4):

Do that using `str.format`:

```
print("0x{:016x}".format(1198540479))
```

result:

```
0x00000000477046bf
```